# How to store form data as draft in django

Tags: django, forms

I'm working on a project that requires to store form data as a draft if the user closes the browser or leave the tab or any other case. and when the user opens the same form next time the user can see the previously entered data

Answer (score 0):

I'd use JavaScript, to be precise detecting changes and saving them at the `localStorage` ([link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)).